# Prove that if $ K_{A} $ is continuous then $FrA =\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be topological space, $K_{A}$ function defined with
$ K_{A} (x) = 1, x \in A, K_{A} (x) = 0, x \in X\backslash A$. Prove that if $ K_{A} $ is continuous then $FrA =\emptyset$ ($FrA=ClA\backslash IntA$).

I tried by contradiction. Since $ClA= A \cup A^{'}$ I decided to separate proof in two cases. First case ($x \in (A^{'}\backslash A)$ ) I easily got contradiction, but on this second case ($x \in (A\backslash A^{'})$ ) I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about what it means for $K_A$ to be continuous.

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ be open. If either $1\in U$ and $0\notin U$, then $K_A^{-1}(U)=A$. If $0\in U$ and $1\notin U$, then $K_A^{-1}(U)=X\setminus A.$ If both are in $U$, then $K_A^{-1}(U)=X.$ Finally, if neither are in $U$, then $K_A^{-1}(U)=\emptyset.$ Since $K_A$ is continuous, these all must be open sets. That is, we need that both $A$ and $X\setminus A$ are open sets. That is, $A$ must be both open and closed. If $A$ is open, then $A=\text{Int} A$, and if $A$ is closed, then $A=\text{Cl}A.$ Thus,  $\text{Cl} A\setminus \text{Int} A=A\setminus A=\emptyset.$